# How do I add root-level routes (not in an area)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, orchardcms, orchard-modules

Complete noob to Orchard here (and CMS's in general), so please correct any misconceptions I may have. I have an existing site that I am trying to rework into an Orchard module. The goal is basically the same site as before, but with the owners having the ability to add their own blog post pages through the Orchard GUI.

This site-as-a-module, which I'll call `SiteModule`, needs to have routes at the root level of the application in order for it to feel like "my site + a CMS" rather than "a CMS + my site".

How do I build the routes in my `SiteModule` so they are in the app root, rather than their default of being in a dedicated `/SiteModule` area?

Answer (score 0):

As you can guess it defaults to this set up to prevent modules stepping on each others toes, but you can easily add your own routes. This code assumes you have two controllers in your module called Home and Default. Create a `Routes.cs` file in the route of your SiteModule project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Orchard.Mvc.Routes;

namespace SiteModule {
    public class Routes : IRouteProvider {
        public void GetRoutes(ICollection<RouteDescriptor> routes) {
            foreach (var routeDescriptor in GetRoutes())
                routes.Add(routeDescriptor);
        }

        public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes() {
            return new[] {
                new RouteDescriptor {
                    Priority = 5,
                    Route = new Route(
                        "Home/{action}",
                        new RouteValueDictionary {
                            {"area", "SiteModule"},
                            {"controller", "Home"},
                            {"action", "Index"}
                        },
                        new RouteValueDictionary(),
                        new RouteValueDictionary {
                            {"area", "SiteModule"}
                        },
                        new MvcRouteHandler())
                },
                new RouteDescriptor {
                    Priority = 5,
                    Route = new Route(
                        "Default/{action}",
                        new RouteValueDictionary {
                            {"area", "SiteModule"},
                            {"controller", "Home"},
                            {"action", "Gogo"}
                        },
                        new RouteValueDictionary(),
                        new RouteValueDictionary {
                            {"area", "SiteModule"}
                        },
                        new MvcRouteHandler())
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I guess just watch out that you aren't overriding any of Orchard's default routes :)